# Can't log in or access recovery!

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I have a 2011 MacBookPro running OS X Yosemite. I was browsing online when suddenly my entire screen went grey (no cursor, completely unresponsive). I restarted the laptop & got the usual "Update Needed" user (I have FileVault on). As soon as it reaches halfway thru the progress bar, it reboots on its own! I tried resetting the SMC, as well as holding down Cmd + R to access recovery. In the latter case, the Apple logo appears with a progress bar underneath. As soon as it reaches halfway thru, the screen turns grey & it just sits there. The same thing happens when I try to boot into safe mode.

Tried many times unsuccessfully. I have a feeling this has to do with FileVault.

Help!

Comment: Yosemite is known for the halfway error. A clean install will suffice. However, usually when you can't even boot to internet recovery it's usually a hardware issue. Try resetting the PRAM and then try rebooting again into recovery mode.

Comment: @soulshined Tried that. Didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my 2011 MacBook Pro is one of several units suffering from a defective GPU.
I realized this issue happens only when I'm doing something GPU-related like using iPhoto or viewing certain webpages. My Mac is now completely unusable & I'm going to have to get a new one.

[Here's more info on this.](http://www.macrumors.com/2014/10/28/macbook-pro-2011-graphics-lawsuit/)